# preg_match pattern to find the contents of a string between <html> and </html> tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a PHP script that reads the content of emails, and pulls out certain information to store in a database.

Using imap_fetchbody ($imap_stream, $msg_number, 1), I'm able to get at the body of the email. In some cases (especially email sent as SMS from mobile phones), the body of the email looks like this:

```
===------=_Part_110734_170079945.1283532109852
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
        <title>Multimedia Message</title> 
    </head> 
    <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0"> 


                <tr height="15" style="border-top: 1px solid #0F7BBC;"> 
                    <td> 
                        SMS to email test
                    </td> 
                </tr> 


     </body> 
</html> 


------=_Part_110734_170079945.1283532109852--===
```

I want to pull out the "content" of the email. So, my plan is this:

Check to see if the body contains the "html" tags. If not, I can read it normally (it's not an HTML email).

If it does, extract the content between the "html" tags. Then, eliminate all the other HTML tags, and the "content" is what's left.

However, I'm pretty clueless when it comes to regex patterns.

I tried this:

```
$pattern = '/<html[^>]*>(.*?)<\/html>/i';
preg_match($pattern, $body, $matches);
// my 'content' should be in $matches[1]
```

But that didn't work (probably because $body contains newlines and other whitespace). So then I tried this:

```
$pattern = '/<html[^>]*>([.\s]*?)<\/html>/i';
preg_match($pattern, $body, $matches);
```

But that didn't work either.

So, what $pattern can I use to extract all the text between the "html" tags?

**UPDATE:** I've stumbled into a workaround - strip all the whitespace first:

```
$body = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $body);
$pattern = '/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/';
```

I suspect this isn't the fastest or most efficient method, but it works, and is the best I've got so far. I'd still appreciate a better solution if there is one, though.

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks to Gumbo suggestions, I've tried a little harder to dig through the structure of the email to find the part I was looking for, instead of attempting to regex HTML. I finally found this: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch17_04.htm, which explains how to do exactly what I needed.

Comment: Why don’t you use the other [IMAP function](http://php.net/ref.imap) to get the multipart body?

Comment: Gumbo - actually, I am (although maybe not correctly). I use imap_fetchbody($imap, $msg_number, 1.1). If that returns an empty string, I use imap_fetchbody($imap, $msg_number, 1). For normal mail, that returns exactly what I want, whichout all the HTML. The issue I'm having is specific to SMS messages sent from mobile phones as email. In that case, I get the text I posted above, regardless. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @mattstuehler: `imap_fetchbody` expects the third parameter to be a string. Did you try `imap_fetchbody($imap, $msg_number, '1.1')`?

Comment: Gumbo - Thanks for your comments and detailed explanation below! Works like a charm. Re: imap_fetchbody - yup - I am passing '1', not 1. This does work for normal email - just not emails sent by cell phones as SMS. So, I guess I just need to work on figuring out how those are constructed differently. In any case, your detailed explanation at least helped me understand regex a little better. Thanks again.

Comment: @mattstuehler: Doesn’t `imap_fetchstructure` give you the right hint?

Comment: @Gumbo - it does. I used it to examine the messages that were giving me problems. It turns out there's another "level" to these messages - so, part "1.1.1" gives me the HTML that represents the body of these messages - the "part" that I'm looking for. Unfortunately, unless I'm mistaken, it looks like there's no plain-text part. It turns out that these messages come from iPhones sending SMS to email addresses. So, I don't know if it's specific to iPhones, SMS to email, or AT&T or what. But, bottom line, there's no plain-text part, so I have to pull the content from HTML one way or another.

Comment: @Gumbo - another thanks. Because of your prodding, I found a little code that helps me find EXACTLY what I'm looking for - the plain-text part of the email - regardless of how it's structured: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch17_04.htm. That's probably just what you hand in mind. Perfect solution, and no regex'ing HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[.\s]` means either a literal `.` or a whitespace character. What you need is either `(.|\s)`, or `[\s\S]`, or you simply set the [*s* modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) to have `.` also match line breaks.

But besides that, [you should not use regular expressions to match HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Parts of HTML are not regular and thus you cannot use regular expressions to describe it.

But besides that, you should not try to guess the range of a multipart content when you have distinct delimiters. But these aren’t `<html>…</html>`. Because what if they are missing? Then your attempt will fail. Use the delimiters defined by the message itself: the [boundary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1) value. So use the boundary to get the parts and split them at the first CRLF+CRLF sequence to separate the header from the body.

But besides that, why don’t you use the [IMAP functions](http://php.net/ref.imap) to get the body? I’m not familiar with the PHP’s IMAP API, but there probably is a function that does exactly that what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
$pattern = '/<html[^>]*>([^\00]*?)<\/html>/i';
```

That will only break if there's a `0x00` byte in the content, which should not be.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an html parser like :
http://php-html.sourceforge.net/

or you can use strip_tags
php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to allow `.` match newlines:

```
$pattern = '/<html[^>]*>(.*?)<\/html>/si';
preg_match($pattern, $body, $matches);
```